# Texturing problem on cylinder

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, faces, reflection

I had to delete a section of this piping and re-build it by bridging the vertices together and filling in the edges as faces.

Then when I turned it onto 'rendered view' I noticed that the metal material I had applied to the surface did not carry over across all of the faces of this object. It looks as if they are not connected. So I have tried to find a solution to this problem. I would like for the material to be applied smoothly and the reflections to run across the surface too. I have 'smooth shading' turned on and 'auto smooth' normals.

If someone knows how I can fix this it would be very much appreciated.

Here are some images illustrating the problem I am facing. https://i.imgur.com/yE2607L.png https://i.imgur.com/NPrXcwQ.png https://i.imgur.com/SNP17YC.png

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like flipped normals.  Tab to edit mode, press A to select all verts, then mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside

Comment: This helped thank you!